# what is the regexp pattern to match abc-adm, 12-2adm4, -5adm and so on

Tags: regex, vbscript

Im using vbscript and basically i need to validate strings which fits something like

```
*-*adm*
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.*-.*adm.*`. The `.*` means "match `.` (any character) `*` (zero or more times)".

Here's a link to Microsoft's VBScript regex documentation, which might prove useful for you should you need to construct more complicated regular expressions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx